# iPhone: Adding a custom view to a UITableView Cell produces weird results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

**What I'm doing:**

I have a custom ViewController called "MoreAppsViewController" - it displays/advertises several of the other apps I have created, and I use this same class/xib etc in several different apps. It controls a small view that gets displayed on options screens.

Normally I can just add this to any view with code such as:

```
MoreAppsViewController * moreApps = [[MoreAppsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreAppsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:moreApps.view];
```

-

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to display the same view in a UITableViewCell. This is the code:

```
moreApps = [[MoreAppsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreAppsViewController" bundle:nil];
[cell.contentView addSubview:moreApps.view];
```

It does get displayed. However, some elements of moreApps.view appear lower than they should - they get drawn below the cell, but the rest of the elements get drawn in the cell correctly. Specifically, it's a scroll view that forms the main part of moreApps.view that gets pushed below where it should be (the scroll view and anything on it).

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it? Any help would be much appreciated!

-

Lastly - The scroll view is just part of the .xib file, I don't do anything weird in the MoreAppsViewController either.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, by 'below' I mean further down the page. If I increase the cell's height, the scroll view is just pushed further down the page.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's what it was doing: (the bit below the cell should be appearing inside it)

[image: TableView Glitch]

Comment: Given the issue seems to be purely visual, can I suggest you add a screenshot to your question so we can get a better understanding of what's going on?

Comment: @micpringle - have found a workaround for now, see below. I'll post a screenshot in a sec anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, placing the scroll view inside a dummy view fixes the problem (via the interface builder). Don't ask me why - feel free to explain though!

Seems to happen for any scroll view on a .xib, when placed inside a UITableViewCell of above default height.